# Calibre web error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xdg-icon-resource' in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, portainer, calibre, xdgutils

Host os: Ubuntu 22.04
device Hewlett Packard Enterprise ProLiant ML350p Gen8

When starting up calibre web it gives me this error:

```
Setting up libedit2:amd64 (3.1-20210910-1build1) ...
Setting up libsensors-config (1:3.6.0-7ubuntu1) ...
Setting up xkb-data (2.33-1) ...
Setting up libxcb-shm0:amd64 (1.14-3ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libopengl0:amd64 (1.4.0-1) ...
Setting up libxxf86vm1:amd64 (1:1.1.4-1build3) ...
Setting up libxcb-present0:amd64 (1.14-3ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libxfixes3:amd64 (1:6.0.0-1) ...
Setting up libxcb-sync1:amd64 (1.14-3ubuntu3) ...
Setting up xz-utils (5.2.5-2ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/xz to provide /usr/bin/lzma (lzma) in auto mode
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzma.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xz.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/unlzma.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/unxz.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzcat.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzcat.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzmore.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzmore.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzless.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzless.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzdiff.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzdiff.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzcmp.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzcmp.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzgrep.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzgrep.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzegrep.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzegrep.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/lzfgrep.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/xzfgrep.1.gz (of link group lzma) doesn't exist
Setting up libsensors5:amd64 (1:3.6.0-7ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libglapi-mesa:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1) ...
Setting up libxcb-dri2-0:amd64 (1.14-3ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libxshmfence1:amd64 (1.3-1build4) ...
Setting up libllvm15:amd64 (1:15.0.6-3~ubuntu0.22.04.2) ...
Setting up libdrm-common (2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libelf1:amd64 (0.186-1build1) ...
Setting up libxkbcommon0:amd64 (1.4.0-1) ...
Setting up libwayland-client0:amd64 (1.20.0-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libdrm2:amd64 (2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libdrm-nouveau2:amd64 (2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libgbm1:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1) ...
Setting up libdrm-radeon1:amd64 (2.4.113-2~ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1) ...
Setting up libegl-mesa0:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1) ...
Setting up libegl1:amd64 (1.4.0-1) ...
Setting up libglx-mesa0:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1) ...
Setting up libglx0:amd64 (1.4.0-1) ...
Setting up libgl1:amd64 (1.4.0-1) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (22.2.5-0ubuntu0.1~22.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
**** Installing/updating calibre ****
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  4  129M    4 6015k    0     0  3829k      0  0:00:34  0:00:01  0:00:33 6045k
 15  129M   15 20.3M    0     0  8121k      0  0:00:16  0:00:02  0:00:14 10.2M
 26  129M   26 34.9M    0     0   9.7M      0  0:00:13  0:00:03  0:00:10 11.6M
 37  129M   37 48.6M    0     0  10.6M      0  0:00:12  0:00:04  0:00:08 12.1M
 48  129M   48 62.8M    0     0  11.2M      0  0:00:11  0:00:05  0:00:06 12.5M
 59  129M   59 77.4M    0     0  11.7M      0  0:00:11  0:00:06  0:00:05 14.3M
 70  129M   70 91.9M    0     0  12.1M      0  0:00:10  0:00:07  0:00:03 14.3M
 82  129M   82  106M    0     0  12.4M      0  0:00:10  0:00:08  0:00:02 14.3M
 92  129M   92  120M    0     0  12.5M      0  0:00:10  0:00:09  0:00:01 14.3M
100  129M  100  129M    0     0  12.6M      0  0:00:10  0:00:10 --:--:-- 14.3M
Creating symlinks...
    Symlinking /app/calibre/ebook-device to /usr/bin/ebook-device
    Symlinking /app/calibre/ebook-meta to /usr/bin/ebook-meta
    Symlinking /app/calibre/ebook-convert to /usr/bin/ebook-convert
    Symlinking /app/calibre/ebook-polish to /usr/bin/ebook-polish
    Symlinking /app/calibre/markdown-calibre to /usr/bin/markdown-calibre
    Symlinking /app/calibre/web2disk to /usr/bin/web2disk
    Symlinking /app/calibre/calibre-server to /usr/bin/calibre-server
    Symlinking /app/calibre/lrf2lrs to /usr/bin/lrf2lrs
    Symlinking /app/calibre/lrs2lrf to /usr/bin/lrs2lrf
    Symlinking /app/calibre/calibre-debug to /usr/bin/calibre-debug
    Symlinking /app/calibre/calibredb to /usr/bin/calibredb
    Symlinking /app/calibre/calibre-parallel to /usr/bin/calibre-parallel
    Symlinking /app/calibre/calibre-customize to /usr/bin/calibre-customize
    Symlinking /app/calibre/fetch-ebook-metadata to /usr/bin/fetch-ebook-metadata
    Symlinking /app/calibre/calibre-smtp to /usr/bin/calibre-smtp
    Symlinking /app/calibre/calibre to /usr/bin/calibre
    Symlinking /app/calibre/lrfviewer to /usr/bin/lrfviewer
    Symlinking /app/calibre/ebook-viewer to /usr/bin/ebook-viewer
    Symlinking /app/calibre/ebook-edit to /usr/bin/ebook-edit
Setting up command-line completion...
Installing zsh completion to: /usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions/_calibre
Failed to find directory to install bash completions, using default.
Installing bash completion to: /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/
Setting up desktop integration...
____________________ WARNING ____________________
Setting up desktop integration failed with error:
__________________________________________________
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "calibre/linux.py", line 858, in setup_desktop_integration
      File "calibre/linux.py", line 880, in do_setup_desktop_integration
      File "calibre/linux.py", line 911, in install_xdg_junk
      File "calibre/linux.py", line 896, in install_icons
      File "calibre/linux.py", line 890, in install_single_icon
      File "subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
      File "subprocess.py", line 345, in call
      File "subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
      File "subprocess.py", line 1842, in _execute_child
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xdg-icon-resource'
Creating un-installer: /usr/bin/calibre-uninstall
There were 1 warnings
* Setting up desktop integration failed with error:
[custom-init] No custom files found, skipping...
[ls.io-init] done.
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  calibre-web:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/calibre-web:latest
    container_name: calibre-web
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/Amsterdam
      - DOCKER_MODS=linuxserver/mods:universal-calibre #optional
      - OAUTHLIB_RELAX_TOKEN_SCOPE=1 #optional
      - UMASK=022
    volumes:
      - /mnt/WesternDigital/Docker/calibreweb:/config
      - /mnt/WesternDigital/Ebooks/library:/books
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    restart: unless-stopped
```

I tried changing PIUD and GUID. Older versions of Calibre web docker image. Also tried portainer and manual docker compose. Has anyone had this in the past? And how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Updated with solution:

I believe the issue is the `#optional` in `- DOCKER_MODS=linuxserver/mods:universal-calibre #optional`

Set it to `DOCKER_MODS=linuxserver/mods:universal-calibre` and it should work